# Array has incomplete element type

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, void, incomplete-type

I try to give my Void function a struct but when I do this I get a errors.
first:error: subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'struct Lager'.
and a warning:warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'Lager (*)[200]' to parameter of type 'struct Lager *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types].
and 
warning: declaration of 'struct Lager' will not be visible outside of this function [-Wvisibility].
I already asked my fellow students but no-one of them could help me.

```
void case1(struct Lager  *wh, int l){

        int end;
        int v;
        char ques;
    do {
        printf("\nEnter the product name:  ");
        scanf("%s",  *(wh[l]).artikel);

        printf("\nAmount of products:  ");
        scanf("%i", &*(wh[l]).anzahl);


        printf("\n\nAdd another product ? (Y/N)");
        // add a space before % to skip leading whitespace
        scanf(" %c", &ques);
        switch (ques) {
            case 'Y':
                v++;
                l++;
                break;
            case 'N':
                end = 1;
                v = 0;
                l++;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Wrong entry\n");
                end = 1;
                break;
        }
    } while (end != 1);
    if (v >= 2) {
        printf("Product added successfully\n\n");
    }else {
        printf("Products have been successfully added\n\n");
    }
}

int main() {

    typedef int item;
    typedef char max;
    typedef int GanzvieleBuchstaben;

    //unien wär die bessere variante (eigentlich). weil platzsparender

    typedef struct managementtool 
    {
        max artikel[200];
        item anzahl;
    }Lager;

    Lager lager[200];

    printf("Welcome to Warehouse Management 97\n\n\nWhat do you want to do ?\n");

    GanzvieleBuchstaben a,l,f,i,v,x,p,c,я,и,ii;
    int exit, end, all;
    int b = 201;

    char ques, nu1;
    char find [100];

    do {
        printf("\n(1)Add article\n(2)Edit article.\n(3)Search entry.\n(4)Show stock.\n(5)Exit\n");
        scanf("%i",&x);

        switch (x) {
            case 1://add

                case1(&lager, l);

      *Irrelevant stuff down there*
```

Comment: `Lager` type is defined inside `main` so the `case1` function won't be able to see it. Instead, define it above the function. Also, the type is `Lager` not `struct Lager` as currently used in the `case1` function.

Comment: There are many other problems. Some of them will be flagged as errors and some as warnings once you fix up the `Lager` problems and you'll need to fix all those one by one.

Comment: Just as a hint on the side, translating everything to English will put most potentially helpfully minded users in a better mood. It also reduces the needed amount of prose explanation.